# Show that $\mathbb R$ satisfies the second axiom of countability

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

In my general topology exercise I have to prove the following:

> A topological space $(X,\tau)$ is said to satisfy the second axiom of countability if there exists a basis $B$ for $\tau$, where $B$ consists of only a countable number of sets.
>
> - Show that $\mathbb R$ satisfies the second axiom of countability

And then they give the tip "use exercise 3", which is:

> Let $B$ be the collection of all open intervals $(a,b)$ in $\mathbb R$, with $a < b$ and $a,b \in \mathbb Q$. Prove that $B$ is a basis for the euclidean topology.

I already proved exercise 3, and I think that the tip basically says to use the basis from exercise 3. So now I have to prove that $B$ has a countable number of sets.

---

**My approach:**

We know that the set $\mathbb Q$ is countable so, let $U_\alpha=\{(\alpha,n), \forall n \in \mathbb{Q}\}$. Then $U_\alpha \sim \mathbb Q$. So every $U_\alpha$ is countable. Now, the family of sets $\mathcal F= \{U_\alpha, \forall \alpha \in \mathbb Q \}$ is also countable because $\mathcal F \sim \mathbb Q$, So $B = \bigcup \mathcal F$ is the union of a countable number of sets.

My question is, is this proof right and is this the most correct way to prove it?

Comment: Yes your proof is correct. You could also do it by observing that there is an injection $B\to\mathbb{Q}^2$ (which sends an interval to its end points), the latter of which is countable. But your way is also already pretty neat.

Comment: That is true, I didn't even thought of that @RedundantAunt thanks